# How to send a postBack crossover to a iframe with html and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I am a begginer in a web programming job, therefore, I come here for help. This is the problem. There is an iframe from another business that provide queries, kind of package tracking, So, I have to import the iframe to our system like this:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid #D5CC5A; overflow    : hidden; margin: 15pxauto; max-width: 58%;">
        <iframe name="my-iframe" scrolling="no"  style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 560px; margin-top: -165px; width: 58%;">
        </iframe>
        </div>
```

and send information in order to fill the iframe and it supposed to return a HTML with the information required in order to display it in our website. I already try to send information this way

```
$('#formi').append('<input type="hidden" name="TextBox1" id="TextBox1" value="28557145">');
$('#formi').append('<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTIxMjg1MzU1NDEPZBYCAgMPZBYEAgcPPCsADQBkAgsPZBYEAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0BRRSOTcyMzM0MSAgICAgICAgICAgIGRkAgMPDxYCHwAFFUd1YXRlbWFsYSwgMTMvMTEvMjAxNWRkGAEFCWdyaWR0cmFjaw9nZD2Atu4avtWL+4xYN1GNGj13gpil" />');
$('#formi').append('<input type="hidden"  name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="6610A72C">');
$('#formi').append('<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">');
$('#formi').append('<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">');
$('#formi').append('<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQKa4L/JCALs0bLrBgLJx9vaDQLPhrqxDwLksPnvB7FGOCSZd14UMi2hR9pv8svRR7WB" ');
document.formi.submit();
```

through:

```
<form action="http://------/-----/track.aspx" target="my-iframe" method="post" id="formi" name="formi">
```

When I do that their server display an error, I think that is something wrong with the viewstate variable.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What error do you get? You can debug with fiddler.

Comment: first of all thanks, well at fiddler I could find this that could be the problem. No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.
No WWW-Authenticate Header is present. and in other hand server show this: <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration> So, I think that It wont show us any error. :(

Comment: Looks like you are missing the authentication information

Comment: I think that its because is  cross-domain, I also tried with jsono, but server does not allow jsonp.